# Having trouble with Azure Mobile Services Xamarin.Android Push Notification sample application

Tags: android, azure, xamarin

I am using the sample application in Windows Azure Mobile Services for Xamarin.Android to build an Android app that can receive push notifications from Azure Mobile Services. I followed the [instructions on the Windows Azure Mobile Services site](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/partner-xamarin-mobile-services-android-get-started-push/) for creating an Android app that will receive a push notification. That is a 2 phase process. Phase 1 is to get the ToDo sample app working that allows you to use Azure Mobile Services as a backend to the sample to-do app. I got that part working no problems. To me that means lots of stuff can be ruled out as a possible cause of my current problem, for example, it means I have all the connections to Azure Mobile Services working and I was able to get the basic Android app running in the emulator.

Where I ran into problems was in Phase 2 which adds the code to receive a push notifications from the Google notification service. I followed those instructions and it compiled, built and deployed just fine but when it comes up in the emulator I see an error message that says "Device does not have package com.google.android.gsf". What little digging I was able to do seemed to indicate that there is some missing Google runtime (com.google.android.gsf). This is my first Xamarin and first Andriod application so you might have to go slow in directing me especially if I have to add an Add-on to the Android SDK.

-Russ

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the emulator you are running supports Google APIs (the Target when you create a VSD).  If you don't have Google APIs as an option in the VSD creation, you can open the Android SDK manager and download the Google APIs version of each SDK you need.

Alternatively, and usually much easier, I would recommend using an actual device with normal Google Android installed on it.